Trying to invoke @angular-eslint/template/prefer-self-closing-tags for inline templates
I've got an .eslintrc.json file that enforces Angular template files (*.html) to use self-closing tags (Angular 18.1 project). But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get that same rule to apply to inline templates. I've included the full file below (it's pretty verbose). But I figured what I would just need to do is add this:
"@angular-eslint/template/prefer-self-closing-tags": "error",
...to the rules section of the "files": [*.ts] section. However, if I do that, I get this error:
You have used a rule which requires '@angular-eslint/template-parser' to be used as the 'parser' in your ESLint config.
If I add @angular-eslint/template-parser to the extends part of the *.ts section, then I get:
Failed to load config "plugin:@angular-eslint/template-parser" to extend from
And anyway, I would have thought the "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates", would do the trick here, but it doesn't.
Any help is appreciated.
Here's the relevant section of my package.json file:
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "18.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "18.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "18.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "18.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "18.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.1.1",

...and the complete .eslintrc.json file:
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["projects/**/*", "**/*.py", "dev_index.html"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["./tsconfig.eslint.json"],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
      ],
      "plugins": ["rxjs"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
          "off",
          {
            "allowExpressions": true
          }
        ],
        "no-await-in-loop": "error",
        "no-extra-parens": "off",
        "no-prototype-builtins": "off",
        "no-template-curly-in-string": "error",
        "valid-jsdoc": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/array-type": [
          "off",
          {
            "default": "array"
          }
        ],
        "accessor-pairs": "off",
        "no-unused-vars": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
          "off",
          {
            "vars": "all",
            "args": "none",
            "ignoreRestSiblings": true,
            "caughtErrors": "none",
            "varsIgnorePattern": "^_",
            "argsIgnorePattern": "^_"
          }
        ],
        "array-callback-return": "error",
        "block-scoped-var": "error",
        "class-methods-use-this": "off",
        "complexity": "off",
        "consistent-return": "error",
        "curly": "error",
        "default-case": "error",
        "dot-location": ["error", "property"],
        "no-console": [
          "off",
          {
            "allow": ["warn", "error"]
          }
        ],
        "dot-notation": "off",
        "eqeqeq": "off",
        "guard-for-in": "off",
        "no-alert": "off",
        "no-caller": "error",
        "no-div-regex": "error",
        "no-else-return": "off",
        "no-empty-function": "off",
        "no-eq-null": "error",
        "no-eval": "error",
        "no-extend-native": "error",
        "no-extra-bind": "error",
        "no-extra-label": "error",
        "no-floating-decimal": "error",
        "no-implicit-coercion": "off",
        "no-implicit-globals": "error",
        "no-implied-eval": "error",
        "no-invalid-this": "off",
        "no-iterator": "error",
        "no-labels": "error",
        "no-lone-blocks": "error",
        "no-loop-func": "error",
        "no-magic-numbers": [
          "off",
          {
            "ignore": [-1, 0, 1],
            "ignoreArrayIndexes": true
          }
        ],
        "no-multi-spaces": [
          "error",
          {
            "ignoreEOLComments": true,
            "exceptions": {
              "AssignmentExpression": true,
              "ArrowFunctionExpression": true,
              "CallExpression": true,
              "VariableDeclarator": true
            }
          }
        ],
        "no-multi-str": "error",
        "no-new": "error",
        "no-new-func": "off",
        "no-new-wrappers": "error",
        "no-octal-escape": "error",
        "no-param-reassign": "off",
        "no-proto": "error",
        "no-restricted-properties": "error",
        "no-return-assign": "error",
        "no-return-await": "error",
        "no-script-url": "error",
        "no-self-compare": "error",
        "no-sequences": "error",
        "no-throw-literal": "error",
        "no-unmodified-loop-condition": "error",
        "no-unused-expressions": "off",
        "no-useless-call": "error",
        "no-useless-concat": "error",
        "no-useless-return": "error",
        "no-void": "error",
        "no-warning-comments": "off",
        "no-with": "error",
        "prefer-promise-reject-errors": "error",
        "radix": "error",
        "require-await": "off",
        "vars-on-top": "off",
        "wrap-iife": "error",
        "yoda": "error",
        "strict": "error",
        "init-declarations": "off",
        "no-catch-shadow": "off",
        "no-label-var": "error",
        "no-restricted-globals": "error",
        "no-shadow": "off",
        "no-shadow-restricted-names": "error",
        "no-undef-init": "error",
        "no-undefined": "off",
        "no-use-before-define": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        "rxjs/no-unsafe-takeuntil": [
          "warn",
          { "alias": ["takeUntilDestroyed"] }
        ],
        "rxjs/no-async-subscribe": ["warn"],
        "rxjs/no-create": ["warn"],
        "rxjs/no-index": ["warn"],
        "rxjs/no-ignored-replay-buffer": ["warn"],
        "rxjs/no-ignored-takewhile-value": ["warn"],
        "rxjs/no-internal": ["warn"],
        "rxjs/no-nested-subscribe": ["warn"],
        "rxjs/no-redundant-notify": ["warn"],
        "rxjs/no-subject-unsubscribe": ["warn"],
        "rxjs/no-unbound-methods": ["warn"],
        "rxjs/no-unsafe-subject-next": ["warn"]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/label-has-associated-control": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/template/valid-aria": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/template/alt-text": "error",
        "@angular-eslint/template/no-autofocus": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/template/no-distracting-elements": "error",
        "@angular-eslint/template/use-track-by-function": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/template/prefer-self-closing-tags": "error"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "excludedFiles": ["*inline-template-*.component.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:prettier/recommended"],
      "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": [
          "warn",
          {
            "parser": "angular"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}


